# Find and "copy" a range to a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have data that comes in into a sheet in certain time intervals, but every time the order might be different.  So now, I want to "copy" the values from the "unsorted" sheet, to a new sheet which is sorted in the order I would like the data to be.  From here on, calculations can be done using fixed references when referring to the "sorted" sheet.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. Determine the location of the label of the needed subset of the data in the unsorted sheet.
2. Determine where the actual needed data is on the sheet (the label is above the data, and one column to the right,  so the data is one row down and one column to the left, and goes on for 32 columns and down 24 rows).

Now I want to do this step:

3. Use a array formula (CSE function) to reference those cells, as seen in this screenshot:

[Trying to copy using CSE reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmGCF.png)

Hitting Ctrl+Shift+Enter shows the result:  *#REF*

What can I do differently?

Comment: What formula are you using?

Comment: That's not how array formulas work - you need VBA to achieve this

Comment: It looks like you are using an `INDIRECT` formula and feeding it a reference string that is in cell K13.  But in cell K13 is an invalid reference of "ASTIR!$A$5:ASTIR!$AF$29".  You don't need the sheet name twice, which is what's causing the #REF! error.  Your K13 cell should instead only display "ASTIR!$A$5:$AF$29"

Comment: Thank you. So either I have to do it VIA VBA, or using regular formulas

Comment: Try `=index(indirect($k$13), row(1:1), column(a:a))` filled right and down with `ASTIR!A5:AF29` in k13. No need for **$** locks here.

Comment: If you can use google sheets instead you can use array functions such as [SORT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) and [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en&ref_topic=3105422) which sounds like exactly what you want to do

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use Google Sheets.

@Jeeped, your formula unfortunately also gives the REF error.I would like to do something like this: http://i.imgur.com/ScodNVe

But what I want to do is have a non-fixed range. I guess it is the INDIRECT causing the error; I think Excel wants to check in the ASTIR sheet's cells where to look, instead of using that range.

Comment: @tigeravatar, you are correct!   For some reason I did not see your message.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Could someone write the accepted solution as an answer?

Comment: I will add tiger's answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback by @*tigeravatar*:

I referenced the range to the ASTIR sheet incorrectly:

> in cell K13 is an invalid reference of "ASTIR!$A$5:ASTIR!$AF$29". You
>   don't need the sheet name twice, which is what's causing the #REF!
>   error.